# elasticsearch-model - how to set TTL option?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-model

I am using elasticsearch-model (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model) but I can't find a way to set the TTL on the documents. I have tried a few ways but without success.

I have a model called "log" and an index called "logs". In the model I have the following mappings:

```
include Elasticsearch::Model

mappings _ttl: { enabled: true, default: '7d' }
```

Which I was hoping it would be similar to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-ttl-field.html#mapping-ttl-field

In the console, this is what I can see:

```
> Log.mappings
=> #<Elasticsearch::Model::Indexing::Mappings:0x007fcefd985368 @mapping={}, @options={:_ttl=>{:enabled=>true, :default=>"7d"}}, @type="log">
```

However, when using cURL, I can only the model properties and not the ttl option:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/logs/_mappings'
{
    "logs": {
        "mappings": {
            "log": {
                "properties": {
                    "created_at": {
                        "format": "dateOptionalTime",
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "operation": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "order_number": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "request_payload": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "response_payload": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "updated_at": {
                        "format": "dateOptionalTime",
                        "type": "date"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried to add the TTL option to the bulk import as an option (to achieve this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/docs-bulk.html#bulk-ttl) but I can't use that option:

```
> Log.import({
  query: -> { where(id: ids) },
  refresh: true,
  return: 'errors',
  ttl: '1d'
})
Unknown key: :ttl. Valid keys are: :start, :batch_size : {"ids":[358]}
```

Any idea on how I can do this?